# How to get the active web form's name?

Tags: vb.net, forms, webforms

I would like to know the method which will allow me to get the active web form's name.
In a windows form it's  `Form.ActiveForm.Name` from the `System.Windows.Form` namespace, but I couldn't find it for a web form, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear as that concept doesn't exists in webforms. Do you mean you want to know in javascript which tab currently has the focus?

Comment: yes please, I want to save in my database the user's ID, the grid name and layout if there is a grid in the user's page and the form's name, I already know how to get the first 3, I still need to get the form's/page name.

Comment: A form doesn't have a name, it has a URL. You can get the url with Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

Comment: Thank you, your answear was very helpfull :)